# How to resize the System Settings window?

Tags: window, system-settings

How do i resize or scroll down system settings windows, please check the pic below

[image]

There is no option to scroll or resize,if more than 1 application indicator added in system settings then i cant see any thing in last

**Is there any way i can resize or how i fix it ??**

### UPDATE

i have also tried similar post but none work, but now i can see all all icons.

[How can I resize the System Settings window?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129863/how-can-i-resize-the-system-settings-window)

By adding a line

```
 <property name="width_request">1000</property>
```

[image]

**But still not resize-able**

### Update

> Now to maximize sound volume, i have to enable workspace then change sound settings

[image]

Same with display settings